# AWS CLI: "Failed to execute script pyi_rth_multiprocessing"

Tags: amazon-web-services, cmd, command-line-interface

I am receiving this error:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\User>aws configure

.
[1592] Failed to execute script pyi_rth_multiprocessing

C:\Users\User>
```

What could be the cause?

Comment: I recommend that you re-install the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/).

Answer (score 0):

try contacting AWS, sometimes they can help with this as many people asked them before.